# User analytics for Events list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Afternoon. I'm trying to get hit rates and usage for events created using the Events webpart. I've tried using the Audit tab under Compliance in the Admin center but it doesn't bring anything back. I've clicked on the events and the URL is https://xxx/_layouts/15/Event.aspx, any help gratefully received.

Comment: I've been able to return hit rates for the events using the audit log, but frustratingly it doesn't give me the title of the event item, the Correlation ID and the Unique TokenID but not the title. Is there a way to get this field to pull through?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you cannot get hit rates and usage of events created by using the Events web part, even though Audit logs.